# Excel VBA: Unfreezing panes of a workbook object's sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Normally the code to unfreeze panes is

```
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
```

But say I have sourceBook of type Workbook and a sheetName of type String. For instance

```
sourceBook.sheets(sheetName)
```

How do I unfreeze the panes on that workbook's sheet without invoking things like ActiveWindow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will remove FreezePanes from every sheet for every window for the given workbook, it also makes sure the same worksheet is active as was active before running the code:

```
Dim w As Window
Dim activews As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
For Each w In sourceBook.Windows
    w.Activate
    If activews Is Nothing Then
        Set activews = w.ActiveSheet
    End If
    For Each wsv In w.SheetViews
        wsv.Sheet.Activate
        w.FreezePanes = False
    Next
    activews.Activate
    set activews = nothing
Next
```

As Rick indicated, you cannot unfreeze panes without activating the window. But you don't have to call `ActiveWindow`.

Comment: Well I am performing a sort procedure on the sheet that has the frozen panes, and it throws an error if it's frozen -- so I must unfreeze it. Is there a way to unfreeze it and return to whatever the previously active window was? EDIT: Nevermind, your code does this. One moment.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't... I left that out because you didn't want to use ActiveWindow. If you want it to do that, just store the activeWindow first like `dim ActiveW as window: set ActiveW = ActiveWindow` and then at the end `activeW.Activate`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still having the same issue 
EDIT: Ninja'd again

Comment: Getting "1004The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank." Not sure if this is because of the new window code or something with the sort code.

Comment: Okay.... I don't see how an error in your sort code could have anything to do with what I posted.

Comment: It was my code. (But it has to do with all the window-switching and unfreeze-paning I'm doing)

It had to do with the references. By switching to another window, I had used Range somewhere instead of correctbook.sheet.Range

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Freeze Panes is a method of a window object, the sheet on which you want to apply it needs to be the activesheet.
This means that you will have to select the cell on which you would like to freeze the panes on the active window only.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code to sheet's activate event (for e.g. this is the code under Sheet1)

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
End Sub
```